# Mock geometry for spatial filtering

Tags: arcobjects, c#, unit-testing

Does anyone know how to mock `IGeometry` (e.g. using NSubstitute)? I want to use it within an `ISpatialFilter`, however I always get an exception on the last line of the code beyond.

> COMException: The geometry property of the spatial filter is invalid.
>   (-2147216814)

When I use a realworld-instance such as `PolygonClass` it works, however if I use this and afterwards do some topological operations (intersect) on them I also use real-world code which I want to avoid.

This is what I have so far:

```
var poly = Substitute.For<IPolygon, IGeometry>();
poly.IsEmpty.Returns(false);
poly.IsClosed.Returns(true);
poly.ExteriorRingCount.Returns(1);
poly.GeometryType.Returns(esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon);
poly.Dimension.Returns(esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry2Dimension);
poly.Length.Returns(2);
var filter = new SpatialFilter
{
    Geometry = (IGeometry)poly,
    SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects
};
```

Comment: Maybe the geometry needs a SpatialReference

Comment: Assigned a new instance of `UnknownCoordinateSystem`, the error remains. However I assume the framework will automatically inject a proxy-type for `ISpatialReference` (as it also does for `Envelope` e.g).